# How to fix this error Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to to install Laravel 5.2 but it doesn't fully load and shows me this error:

```
>Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why not install a more recent version of Laravel? 5.2 is several years old now.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't fully load"?

Comment: @GregSchmidt yeah i know but i need it for specific program.

Comment: @DelenaMalan actually it dosent make my project folder in directory path.

Comment: @Amirkarim what command are you using to create the project?

Comment: @DelenaMalan this `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test_project "5.2.*"`

Comment: You could try `git clone --single-branch --branch 5.2 https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git test_project && cd test_project && composer install` and see if it makes any difference. The warning you got won't go away, but at least the project should be installed.

Comment: @Delena Malan thank you brother .... i decide to use another virsion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PHPUnit version           PHP Version          composer
   -----------------       ---------------       -------------------------
   PHPUnit 8                PHP 7.2 / 7.3         "phpunit/phpunit": "^8"
   PHPUnit 7                PHP 7.1               "phpunit/phpunit": "^7"
   PHPUnit 6                PHP 7.0               "phpunit/phpunit": "^6"
   PHPUnit 5                PHP 5.6               "phpunit/phpunit": "^5"
```

**Note**: PHP 7.1 is no longer actively supported.

See this [link](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html)

composer: add  `--ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Trying to perform core updated of Drupal 8 and I get the same error. However --ignore-platform-reqs option doesn't help here. I get the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In the composer file you can write this string:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0"
```