# Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested

Tags: laravel

I am going to install ConsoleTVs/Charts in Laravel 5.4 version with PHP(Version 7.3.6) but I have faced with the following error, is there any solution way how to fix this one?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhXxV.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix this error Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Noreplacement was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696556/how-to-fix-this-error-package-phpunit-phpunit-mock-objects-is-abandoned-you-sho)

Answer (score 0):

First find out which package makes you require the abandoned package
`composer depends phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects`

If it is a direct dependency of your composer.json, remove it and use an alternative way of mocking

If it is a dependency of a dependency then:

- Check if the dependency requiring `phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects` can be updated
- Replace the dependency requiring `phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects`
- Contribute to the package with an update replacing `phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects`